# UWP XAML Custom Command Bar Toggle Button

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, customization, resourcedictionary

I'm trying to create a custom AppBarToggleButton for CommandBar which will react as *favorite/unfavorite* button using only XAML ThemeResource. I want it to change icon from `OutlineStart` to `SolidStar` and button label from `Favorite` to `Unfavorite` as on my screenshot bellow.
[Exact result that I want to achieve is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9YKr.png).

Here is the code behind this: [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/LilyStilson/b4ce7a061569f63f9daa9e26625d87f7)

My problem is that while this code is working fine in **XAML Studio** application, it throws `Uncaught exception` in **Visual Studio 2017 Community**. It also works fine in **Visual Studio** designer.

I know that I can achieve the same through code like

```cs
private void ToggleFavorite_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    ToggleFavorite.Text = "Unfavorite";
    ToggleFavorite.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.SolidStar);
}
private void ToggleFavorite_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    ToggleFavorite.Text = "Favorite";
    ToggleFavorite.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.OutlineStar);
}
```

but that is not what I want, I'm interested in XAML customization and I want to do it exactly from XAML style.

What can I do to make it work in **Visual Studio 2017**?

**EDIT (05.03.2020)**: After revising my code, I noticed that **Visual Studio** highlights this line as error

```xml
<Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
```

This happened because I changed name of `ContentPresenter` from `Content` to `ViewboxContentPresenter` here

```xml
<Viewbox x:Name="ContentViewbox" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonContentHeight}" Margin="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonContentViewboxCollapsedMargin}">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ViewboxContentPresenter" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
        <ContentPresenter.Content>
            <SymbolIcon Symbol="OutlineStar" />
        </ContentPresenter.Content>
    </ContentPresenter>
</Viewbox>
```

So, that is why `Unhandled Exception` was thrown. After renaming all of this setters' targets, everything started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VisualStateManager` to achieve your requirement.

Use `StateTrigger` to bind the `AppBarToggleButton`'s `IsChecked` property.
Use `Setter` to set the property after the button is checked.

```
<Grid>
        <CommandBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <AppBarToggleButton x:Name="toggleBtn" Icon="UnFavorite" Label="UnFavorite"/>
        </CommandBar>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="checkedbtn">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding ElementName=toggleBtn, Path=IsChecked}"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="toggleBtn.Icon" Value="Favorite"/>
                        <Setter Target="toggleBtn.Label" Value="Favorite"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Can I also change button color using this?

Comment: For other `Button`s, yuou can use this way, but for `AppBarToggleButton`, we can't change it's `Background`, it not works. Even you set like this. <AppBarToggleButton Background="Red"/>. But you can create a custom `AppBarToggleButton.xaml`, change it's color when checked and unckecked and apply the style to this button.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, I overrided the AppBarRevealToggleButton style, then made changes in it, but after I press this button, application crashes with `Unhandled Exception` error. But all my changes work fine in **XAML Studio**. I just don't understand why they don't work in **Visual Studio**.

Comment: Have you add `FavoriteButtonStyle.xaml` to `App.xaml`,    ·<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FavoriteButtonStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>·